# Bootstrap CDN custom css beginner query

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

Is there a way we can include a custom css file when we are linking our relative stylesheets from the link ?

***I must mention that I just downloaded the starter template from bootstrap. and using it as a standalone page. I am just making a normal static page .***

```
<link href="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I just want to change the color of the navbar and I figured I need to include a custom css. I made one but nothing is changing . So I am wondering if I am doing it right .

Here's my custom css link :

```
<link href="custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

and my `custom.css` file

```
.navbar-inner {
  background-color: #FFFF0A; /* fallback color, place your own */

  /* Gradients for modern browsers, replace as you see fit */
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #333333, #222222);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #333333, #222222);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#333333), to(#222222));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #333333, #222222);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #333333, #222222);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #333333, #222222);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;

  /* IE8-9 gradient filter */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#333333', endColorstr='#222222', GradientType=0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the order of your css files ? your custom.css should be after the bootstrap.css . Would help if you could paste the source code of the webpage.

P.S. Sorry I should have wrote it in a comment but I am not able to do so